# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 62

Tags: java, android, json, dictionary, gson

I am facing a problem about the GSON json to Java. I looked up many posts here, but I cannot find the solution for my question. So I list my problem here.I am trying to get the data there is a Map in json but I am not able to retrieve the data . In my log I am able to see that only this much data is coming then it throws the exception . Someone please guide me a way through. Thanks very much !

Here is my Json Data on hitting the URL from the Android app i am working on

### **EDIT**

```
{
"success" : true,
"messages" : {
    "success" : [
        "SEARCH_QUERY_SUCCESS"
    ]
},
"session" : {
    "id" : "cn694ivr8bmqnrveh9n8841oh7",
    "expire" : "",
    "YII_CSRF_TOKEN" : "4fa0ae103b547836241f5278311839b407050919"
},
"metadata" : {
    "product_count" : "4458",
    "category_ids" : "3",
    "results" : [{
            "id" : "105089",
            "data" : {
                "sku" : "MA851AA10ZLX",
                "name" : "Alexa Mid Rise Super Skinny Leg",
                "new-product" : false,
                "url" : "http:\/\/theiconic.bugfoot.de\/mobile-api\/Alexa-Mid-Rise-Super-Skinny-Leg-105089.html",
                "simples" : {
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406437" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406438" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406439" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406440" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406441" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406442" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406443" : {},
                    "MA851AA10ZLX-406444" : {
                        "meta" : {
                            "sku" : "MA851AA10ZLX-406444",
                            "price" : "149.99",
                            "caching_hash" : "78ddaaf930f8bd0e0bf595c25643683d",
                            "shipment_cost_item" : "0.00",
                            "shipment_cost_order" : "0.00",
                            "tax_percent" : "10.00",
                            "quantity" : "2",
                            "cost" : "64.09",
                            "size_brand" : "W31\/L34",
                            "size" : "W31\/L34",
                            "size_position" : "200",
                            "3hours_shipment_available" : true,
                            "estimated_delivery" : "",
                            "estimated_delivery_position" : ""
                        },
                        "attributes" : {
                            "sort_order" : "0",
                            "size" : "W31\/L34"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

### **Edit**

This is my network class used for parsing

```
String jsonString = null;

    try {
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if (httpClient != null) {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            jsonString = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(jsonString);

    if (jsonString != null) {
        Bean obj=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Bean.class);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = obj;
        responseHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        //obj can be sent to a handler 
    }
}
}
```

This is Simples Bean class containing a Map

```
public class Simples {
private Map<String, KeyMap> keyMap;
public Map<String, KeyMap> getKeyMap() {return keyMap;}
public void setKeyMap(Map<String, KeyMap> keyMap) {this.keyMap = keyMap;}}
```

This is my KeyMap Bean class

```
public class KeyMap {

private Meta meta;
private Attributes attributes;

public Meta getMeta() {
    return meta;
}

public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
    this.meta = meta;
}

public Attributes getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}

public void setAttributes(Attributes attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
}
}
```

Comment: You're not providing relevant info in the question

Comment: You should post at least the code section where you parse the JSON structure.

Comment: Post your model class

Comment: @karansingh1487 first your json format is not valid , other thing is that you have not posted your model classes

Comment: hi i would post them in the evening when i get home  sorry for inconvenience caused ..... sorry for delay please bear with me

Comment: @bhutto below is  the code

Comment: @Mus below is the code

Comment: @Robert code is given below plz check

Comment: @bhutto Simples class in array is null on checking with debugger

Comment: @Robert thanks for your update on editing the code above instead of making it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Actually your were getting error `BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING` because gson was expecting object not the string, also it is an object in json, you have wrong mapped your classes in  Bean class, and you have not posted the Bean,Simple class glue code here.

You JSON model classes can be mapped as like this

```
public class ProductInfo {
    private boolean success;
    private Map<String, String[]> messages;
    private SessionData session;
    private MetaData metadata;
}
public class SessionData {
    private String id;
    private String expire;
    private String YII_CSRF_TOKEN;
}
public class MetaData {
    private String product_count;
    private String category_ids;
    private List<Result> results;
}
public class Result {
    private String id;
    private Data data;
}
public class Data {
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    @SerializedName(value = "new-product")
    private String newProduct;
    private String url;
    Map<String, KeyMap> simples;
}
public class KeyMap {
    private Meta meta;
    private Attributes attributes;
}

public class Meta {
    private String sku;;
    private String price;
    private String caching_hash;
    private String shipment_cost_item;
    private String shipment_cost_order;
    private String tax_percent;
    private String quantity;
    private String cost;
    private String size_brand;
    private String size;
    private String size_position;
    @SerializedName(value = "3hours_shipment_available")
    private String hours_shipment_available;
    private String estimated_delivery;
    private String estimated_delivery_positio;
}
public class Attributes {
    private String sort_order;
    private String size;
}
```

Finally de-serialize it

```
ProductInfo productInfo = gson.fromJson(reader, ProductInfo.class);
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks fr reply but my Bean Class is same as your ProductInfo class just one change  i have not taken Map for messages is that why i have encountered the problem ?

Comment: also Simples class is mentioned above .

Comment: my simple bean is coming Null
though i do not get any exception in it